# Running Streamlit APP 1.32.2 Version - Can not delete warning message `label` got an empty value

Tags: python, streamlit

Every time i run my Streamlit Web app terminal sends a warning message always that i interact with the app:

> `label` got an empty value. This is discouraged for accessibility reasons and may be disallowed in the future by raising an exception. Please provide a non-empty label and hide it with label_visibility if needed

I checked the widgets and widgets arguments but maybe i am not watching something.

Steps to Reproduce

1. Copy python code into a python file in your Visual Studio Code 'form.py'
2. Install python library: `streamlit==1.32.2`

- Example command to use: `pip install`
- Extra information: Use virtual environment`venv`

3. Run web app from file directory of main file `streamlit run ./form.py`

Environment information

- Python version: `Python 3.12.2`
- SO: Windows
- Streamlit version: `streamlit==1.32.2`
- Code Editor: Visual Studio Code

Code

```
import streamlit as st 
import pandas as pd
import os 
from datetime import datetime

with st.form('myform'):

    st.subheader('Registration Form')

    c1, c2, c3 = st.columns(3)
    select_box = c1.selectbox('',('Mr','Mrs','Miss'))
    first_name = c2.text_input('First Name', '')
    last_name = c3.text_input('Last Name', '')
    # Role
    role = st.selectbox('Designation',('Software',
        'Sr. Software','Technical Lead',
        'Manager','Sr. Manager','Project Manager'))
    # Date of Birth
    dob = st.date_input('Date of Birth',
         min_value=datetime(year=1900,month=1,day=1))
    # Gender
    gender = st.radio(
        "Select Gender",
        ('Male','Female','Prefered Not to Say')
        )
    # age
    age = st.slider('Age',min_value=1,max_value=100,step=1,value=20)
    submitted = st.form_submit_button('Submit')
    if submitted:
        st.success('Form Subimitted Sucessfully')
        details = {
        'Name': f"{select_box} {first_name} {last_name}",
        'Age': age,
        'Gender':gender,
        'Data of Birth': dob,
        'Designation':role

        }
        st.json(details)
```